# how to use javascript variable within html style tag

Tags: javascript, html, variables, tags

In my angular2 project, I would like to make use of a progress bar thats linked to a variable in my ts file.

So the variable looks like this:

```
public width = 60;
```

then in my html file, i have an html tag that looks like:

```
style="width: 50%"
```

, which i would like to link to that variable.

My best guess is that it would look like `style="width: {{width}}%"`, which is incorrect.

Comment: If you're just looking to set the width of the element, you could just select it and set it from there.

Comment: Read the docs...use ngStyle: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: no i cant just set it in the html file.. it needs to be variable